id column in the subquery where clause exists in both tables, the id it is using is from the wrong table
Table tblStudents columns: id, name, gender, SchoolName, SchoolId.
Table tblSchool columns: id, name, location.
select name,
    (select name
    from tblStudents as a
    where a.SchoolId=id
    limit 1)
from tblSchool;

I am looking to return SchoolName along with the first student enrolled in it.
(That's why I am using limit 1.)
There might be multiple tblStudents records with the same SchoolId in tblStudents.
Since the id column in the where clause exists in both tables, the id it is using with the query belongs to tblStudents, instead of tblSchool.
I can't use aliasing with tblSchool.

add sample data & expected output to understand easily @DeepankarJoshi

Post the task itself, not your attempt to solve it only. Now my query is like this Looks like the task is "select one random student for each school"..

Then don't alias tblSchool, just simply write tblSchool.id in the subquery's where clause. Although I'm not sure if this subquery would return the first student, who enrolled into a school. It will return one random student, who enrolled into that school.

I am looking to return School Name along with the first student enrolled in it. What criteria allows to understand what some definite student of a schooll is "first"?

SELECT s.name AS SchoolName,
   (SELECT a.name
    FROM tblStudents AS a
    WHERE a.SchoolId = s.id
    LIMIT 1) AS FirstStudentName
    FROM tblSchool AS s;

you can't use aliasing for tblSchool, but need to ensure that your subquery uses the id from tblSchool and not from tblStudents.

Yes, I can't use aliasing with tblSchool. That's the condition.

If aliasing is not allowed, you will need to explicitly reference the tables in the subquery without using table aliases
SELECT tblSchool.name AS SchoolName,        (SELECT tblStudents.name         FROM tblStudents         WHERE tblStudents.SchoolId = tblSchool.id         LIMIT 1) AS FirstStudentName FROM tblSchool; 

Thanks hero, didn't thought of that :)

@HarshKushwaha please make an ANSWER out of it versus the above. btw thx for helping the gent
